# Particle systems with lamps as the object emitted

Tags: particles

I'm currently using Blender 2.69. I was reading up on particle systems in Blender's wiki user manual and I noticed that according to the documentation that in addition to having other object primitives emitted as particles that lamps could be used as well. I tried this out using a simple point light. When I tested the particle animation in wireframe mode I could see that my emitter was emitting the lamps, but the nothing would show up in a render. Could anyone tell what I was doing wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Works for me in both BI and cycles. Could you upload your .blend?

Comment: Did you have anything in your scene to light? You won't notice a change unless there are objects for the lights to effect.

Comment: I'm feeling that you are trying to emit lamps as they are halos. But they are not, actually. Lamp objects, by itself, cannot be seen in render, unless you use objects with emit shading. This is nothing about particles. If this is what puzzles you.

Comment: Once I put a plane in the scene they did show up. The particles acted as expected dying after a period of time and the light in the scene faded. It was interesting experiment and I hope to do something with it :)

Comment: @LeonCheung Perhaps you could add an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It is nothing about particle system actually.

As you see, there are some non-mesh type of objects cannot be rendered, such as lamps/bones/cameras/lattices/empties, etc, since they don't have any solid face to render. However, you can still see their effects around the scene as ususal.

Anyway, other options here would be:

**For BI:**

- Instead of lamp, use mesh object with **Emit** shading enabled;
- Group lamp with mesh object, set mesh material type to **Halo**, emit the whole group as particle unit.

**For Cycles:**

- Use mesh object as particle unit, use **Emission** shader for material setting. (recommended)